# Einstein Chat Bot - dynamic routing; additional interrogation; agent not available

Tags: einstein, bots

How can I dynamic rout a chat based on the customer's selected option?
For example I have English and France support (separated queues), can I setup the chat bot that if the customer selects the french button, the case will be assigned to the french queue?

Is it possible to setup additional interrogation based on the records found in the system? For example if based on the pre-chat form there are multiple accounts with the same email address, is it possible for the chant bot to detect that and request additional info (like the social ID number)?

Is it possible to change the message that a customer see when he requests to be transferred to an agent and there is no agent online?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Direct-to-Button Routing - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_directtobutton_routing.htm

If you want custom logic(Second requirement) you can use a custom pre-chat form(lightning component) and handle your business logic there.

In case no agent is available bot will call No Agent Available default dialog, change the messaging there.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic routing OOTB feature- https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_service_bots_transfer.htm

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.